# Automate Login to another site PHP

Tags: php, post

I would like to automate logging onto another site using php.  So when I log into my web server, I get a link to... Log in to Facebook.  Log in to gmail etc.  So I want to store my usernames and passwords in my local mysql database.  I don't think I want to use CURL because I don't want to have the Server log on to the website, I want the client browser to actually post to the external website's form handler in order to log in.  All of the examples I see seem to use curl.

Comment: Why would you want to keep the log info on your localhost? If the issue is about needing a central/single login, why not stick to something like OpenID?

Comment: what do you mean by login to facebook and gmail when you have username and password, what really is it that you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason all of the examples are in CURL is because you have to do a post under the covers if you do not want to leave the local server.

If you do not mind leaving your server you just need to find what fields the end form (facebook, gmail, etc) needs and put them in an a post that auto submits with a bit of JavaScript...

```
<form action='http://server.com/login' method='post' name='frm'>
<?php
foreach ($parameter as $a => $b) {
    print("<input type='hidden' name='".$a."' value='".$b."'>");
}
?>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.frm.submit();
</script>
```

The above example can also be adapted to use Ajax as well.

Comment: if the login site has dynamic fields (token etc) this does not work